# 'module' object has no attribute 'scan'.learn python the hard way ex48

Tags: python, python-2.7

I know there're already many people who asked this questions look like this but I really can't find a solution which works for me.

In  ex48. I write the "lexicon.py" and nosetests it.but it reports an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\nose\case.py", line 197, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "D:\pyhomework\ex48\skeleton\tests\lexicon_tests.py", line 31, in test_errors
    assert_equal(Lexicon.scan("ASDFASDF"),[('errors','ASDFASDF')])
```

**AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'scan'**

this is lexicon.py:

```
class Lexicon(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.dic = {'direction':('north','south','east'),
            'verb':('go','kill','eat'),
            'stop':('the','in','of'),
            'noun':('bear','princess'),
            'number':('1234','3','91234'),
            'error':('ASDFASDF','IAS')}

    def scan(self,words):
        self.word = words.split()
        self.result = []
        for item in self.word:
            for key,value in self.dic.items():
                if item in value:
                    self.result.append((key,item))
        return self.result
```

this is lexicon_tests.py

```
from nose.tools import *
from ex48 import Lexicon


def test_direction():
    assert_equal(Lexicon.scan("north"),[('direction','north')])
    result = Lexicon.scan("north south east")
    assert_equal(result,[('direction','north'),('direction','south'),('direction','east')])

def test_verbs():
    assert_equal(Lexicon.scan("go"),[('verb','go')])
    result = Lexicon.scan("go kill eat")
    assert_equal(result,[('verb','go'),('verb','kill'),('verb','eat')])

def test_stops():
    assert_equal(Lexicon.scan("the"),[('stop','the')])
    result = Lexicon.scan("the in of")
    assert_equal(result,[('stop','the'),('stop','in'),('stop','of')])

def test_nouns():
    assert_equal(Lexicon.scan("bear"),[('noun','bear')])
    result = Lexicon.scan("bear princess")
    assert_equal(result,[('noun','bear'),('noun','princess')])

def test_numbers():
    assert_equal(Lexicon.scan("1234"),[('number','1234')])
    result = Lexicon.scan("3 91234")
    assert_equal(result,[('number','3'),('number','91234')])

def test_errors():
    assert_equal(Lexicon.scan("ASDFASDF"),[('errors','ASDFASDF')])
    result = Lexicon.scan("bear IAS princess")
    assert_equal(result,[('noun','bear')('error','IAS')('noun','princess')])
```

this is the skeleton:

```
-bin
-docs
-ex48 (-__init__.py  -Lexicon.py)             
-tests (-__init__.py  -lexicon_tests.py)
-setup
```

I have tried several ways but still get the same error.
thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write `from ex48 import Lexicon` what is imported is the Lexicon.py file as a python module. Yet, this module contains a Lexicon class, which contains the method you want to use.

To get rid of your error, try this import statement : `from ex48.lexicon import Lexicon` this way you will use the `Lexicon` object that is defined in the lexicon.py file.

Answer (score 0):

```
from ex48 import Lexicon
```

So you imported the *module* `lexicon.py`.

In your *module* `lexicon.py` you have a *class* `Lexicon`.

So to call *methods* of the class `Lexicon` you have to use notation

```
Lexicon.Lexicon.method()
```